# NSURLSession Not Reaching Server

Tags: ios, arduino, nsurlsession

I've created an iPhone app for my Arduino, and basically, the Arduino can communicate over the local network using very basic commands provided by a 3rd party REST API.  I've successfully been able to use the API via my computer's web browser, but when trying to send a request to it via an iPhone app, it doesn't seem to want to work.  Also keep in mind, I can get the API to respond properly via Safari on my iPhone.  The only response I'm getting (inside the console) is:

```
{ URL: http://192.168.0.216/mode/7/0 } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
} } : <7b226d65 73736167 65223a20 2250696e 20443722 6964223a 20223030 38222c20 226e616d 65223a20 226d6967 6874795f 63617422 2c202263 6f6e6e65 63746564 223a2074 7275657d 0d0a>
```

The API is indeed supposed to return JSON data, but the response on the web browser actually affects my Arduino's LED.

**Code for Turning the LED on**

```
NSURL *modeSet = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.216/digital/%d/1", _pin]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:modeSet
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", response, data]);
        }] resume];
```

EDIT: I decided to print out the 'Error' variable to see if it was holding anything back from me, and I found this:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x17807b840 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.216/mode/7/o,
NSUnderlyingError=0x178449450 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1001.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.216/mode/7/o}
```

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. Convert the JSON data to a string and NSLog or to a object and NSLog the object to see what is being returned.

Comment: The question is how come it's not actually reaching the Arduino?  I'm getting a response, but it says the connection is closed with the status code 200 (successful) and the JSON is not what it should be.  The JSON in the browser is in English.

Comment: It is reaching the Arduino, that is why there is a return a status of 200 and a JSON response of `{"message": "Pin D7"id": "008", "name": "mighty_cat", "connected": true}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pre-iOS 9 Answer**

Answering my own question so if anyone finds this by Google sometime, they won't have to ask.
All I did was formatted my string correctly with NSUTF8Encoding like so:

```
NSString *modeSetString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.216/mode/%d/o", _pin] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *modeSet = [NSURL URLWithString:modeSetString];
```

**iOS 9 Update**

`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is now deprecated and `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` should be used instead like so:

```
NSString *modeSetString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.216/mode/%d/o", _pin] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
NSURL *modeSet = [NSURL URLWithString:modeSetString];
```